# Ruby loop to puts two different messages

Tags: ruby

I have some brain eclipse, let's say I've got a method:

```
def conditionals(x)
  case
  when x > 2
    puts "x is greater than 2"
  when x == 3
    puts "x is 3"
  else
    puts "I can't guess the number"
  end
end
```

If `x = 3` I want to print two messages:

```
x is greater than 2
x is 3
```

Right now it will print me only one:

```
x is greater than 2
```

How to modify this loop?

Comment: Today I learned how puts works

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? There are no loops anywhere in your code, so how are we supposed to tell you how to modify them, when you don't show them to us?

Comment: Ruby's `case` only evaluates the first matching `when` block and doesn't provide [fallthrough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def conditionals(x)
  puts "x is greater than 2" if x > 2
  puts "x is 3" if x == 3
  puts "I can't guess the number" if x <= 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using `case` statements over `if` statements. Is there a reason you can't have two conditionals?

```rb
def conditionals(x)
  if x == 3
    puts "x is 3"
  end
  if x > 2
    puts "x is greater than 2"
  else
    puts "I can't guess the number"
  end
end
```